# ini_set include_path not working

Tags: php, php.ini

It seems something on my server has been changed, and I'm seeing the inclusion failed error message on my every website on the server, here is one example:

```
Warning: require(xconstants_fa.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/blahblah/public_html/fa/companies/ads/index.php on line 26
```

And in line 26 it says:

```
ini_set ("include_path", "../../includes/");
require "xconstants_fa.php";
```

So it's obvious that somehow my server has stopped using the "ini_set" function(because it was just working fine before), I looked into php.ini disable_functions, nothing is there, I commented all the disabled functions and also the open_basedir, not working there.

and if I:

```
ini_set ("include_path", "../../includes/") or die('ERROR HERE');
```

It echos `ERROR HERE` on the page

What's happening here? I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to check PHP Error logs as it may explain in more detail what the problem is.

### php_admin_value could be set

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

> php_admin_value name value Sets the value of the specified directive.
>   This can not be used in .htaccess files. Any directive type set with
>   php_admin_value can not be overridden by .htaccess or ini_set(). To
>   clear a previously set value use none as the value.

### suhosin could be installed

http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/

### sessions could be getting in the way

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384416/cant-use-ini-set-because-session-is-active

> Warning: ini_set() [function.ini-set]: A session is active. You cannot
>   change the session module's ini settings at this time in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs******.php on line 3